# Index on edges of graph database

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

How to implement index on the edges of graph databases ?

Like :

```
CREATE INDEX <index_name> ON <edge_name> (<edge_property>) DICTIONARY
```

Comment: I am using orientDB for the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You have to create the Edge :

```
CREATE CLASS MyEdge IF NOT EXISTS EXTENDS E
```

Then, Create the Property where you want to put an index :

```
CREATE PROPERTY MyEdge.MyProperty IF NOT EXISTS STRING
```

Finally, You can create your index :

```
CREATE INDEX MyIndex ON MyEdge (MyProperty) DICTIONARY
```